# Is there any way to run a script on any SSH connect/disconnect?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'd like to change my terminal color depending on ssh connected HOSTNAME.

I know how to modify the terminal, but how can I instrument ssh to add hooks?

I could wrap the ssh command with a shell function, or replace the binary, but its used as a dependency by other apps, and I would rather not do that.

Comment: Note: I do not want to just adjust the PS1

Comment: What do you mean by "change my terminal color"?

Comment: how about a bash function? ssh() { pre-action; ssh "$@"; post-action }

Comment: Terminal background color, I mean, which cannot be done with bashrc settings.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `LocalCommand` feature of `OpenSSH` when connecting to a remote server:

```
 LocalCommand
         Specifies a command to execute on the local machine after successfully connecting to the server.  The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed
         with the user's shell.  The following escape character substitutions will be performed: ‘%d’ (local user's home directory), ‘%h’ (remote host name), ‘%l’ (local host
         name), ‘%n’ (host name as provided on the command line), ‘%p’ (remote port), ‘%r’ (remote user name) or ‘%u’ (local user name).

         The command is run synchronously and does not have access to the session of the ssh(1) that spawned it.  It should not be used for interactive commands.

         This directive is ignored unless PermitLocalCommand has been enabled.
```

There is probably no easy way to execute a command when ending a connection with a remote server though apart from writing a `ssh` wrapper.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for confirming there is no easy way to run a command at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A Wrapper around SSH may be your best bet, even though you have discounted it.   However almost every program lets you specify the 'ssh' command they use.

In my I own case I have a 'r' command to replace 'ssh' which performs account lookups (username and host aliases and DNS expansion without relying on the 'DNS resolver domain list', amoungst other things).  These Are my notes to get various programs to call 'r' instead of 'ssh'.

```
scp
  No config or environment variables, you must use option  "-Sr"
     scp -Sr ...
rsync
  set environment variable
    RSYNC_RSH="r -x"
unison
  In ".unison/default.prf"
    sshcmd = r
    sshargs = -q -x
cssh
  In ".clusterssh/config"
    ssh=r
    ssh_args= -x -o ConnectTimeout=10
multixterm
  Use   multixterm -xc "r %n" hostname...
vim netrw (file explorer)
    Have it use the "rsync" command (set above)...
       vim rsync://hostname/
    OR for vim scp://hostname/...
      In ".vimrc" configuration, redefine scp command to use.
        let g:netrw_list_cmd="r USEPORT HOSTNAME ls -Fa1"
        let g:netrw_scp_cmd="scp -Sr -q"
```

My 'r' script decodes all SSH arguments, I have seen used, and even handles very OLD "rsync" commands that placed more options AFTER the hostname!  (Yes, I have been using this script a long time)